# Alternative ways to list files executable by all

Tags: shell, files, permissions, find

I'm looking for all the alternative ways you can think of to list the files which are executable by anyone (owner, group, others) in the current directory and subdirectories.

For alternative ways, I mean those not using the find command:

```
find -L . -type f -perm -111
find -L . -type f -perm -a=x
```

One method that I'd like to see is a combination of ls and grep.

Comment: Are you in an OS that has the `stat` command?

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention it, but as you can see from the question tags, the answers are meant for bash.

Comment: To be able to execute a file, one also needs to have search permission to the directory its in, so it's not just a matter of looking _only_ at the file's permissions.

Comment: `bash` has no `stat` builtin. `zsh` does have a `stat` builtin command, but many systems also have a `stat` command (with varying syntax) that you can call from any shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You are right, although you can omit that control in this case and take the search permission for granted.

Comment: Again `bash` has no builtin `stat` command. The `stat` command you get on Ubuntu is the one in `/usr/bin`. That is the GNU `stat` command from GNU coreutils, it has nothing to do with `bash`. It's the same `stat` command you'd get from any other shell on that system except `zsh` after `zmodload zsh/stat`.

Comment: Just because bash is your shell doesn't mean is can slice bread and butter toast. You want a command-line that will accomplish the goal, or do you want a solution that relies *only* on bash built-ins?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I was not aware of the existance of multiple `stat` (I apology for this). Anyway, the goal is just to find good elegant and efficient alternatives, no matter what you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `ls` and `grep`:

```
ls -lAR | grep "^\-..x..x..x"
```

-l: Shows permissions in rwx format.

-R: Recursive.

Comment: A file with permissions `-rx-rx-rx-` is also executable by all. And you regex matches filenames too.

Comment: As pointed out by Kusalanananda, your pattern doesn't match all possible cases.

Comment: @Kusalananda Correct, I misunderstood the question. Edit in order to use wildcards in grep.

Comment: It will still match on the filenames, and it will display the `ls -l` output for each found file, but give no indication as to where this file is.

Comment: @Kusalananda grep modified to check only in the first column of results. The question did not mention about saying where the file is, so I omitted that, but will look a way to do it.

Comment: It was not a requirement to indicate also where the executable file is located, so this could be actually considered as the first possible alternative.

Comment: Also note that `ls` may not display the name of the actual file in all circumstances.  A file with an embedded `$'\n'` shows as having an embedded `?` on my system, for example.

Comment: @Kusalananda, that quoting of special characters (translated to `?` or other) is supposed to only happen when stdout is a terminal (though busybox ls also known to do it when it's not a  terminal)

Comment: That still misses world-executable suid/sgid files or files with the sticky bit.

Comment: With some `ls` implementations, that could give false positives if there's a directory called `-paxmax2x` for instance.

Comment: Note that it won't work properly if file or dir names or symlink targets contain newline characters.

Comment: Note that, it behaves differently from the OP's solution for symlinks and also in that it will skip hidden files.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Directory called -paxmax2x shouldn't be a false positive because I only take into account the first column of `ls -l` output (the column which tells file permissions) and not the filename. I added -A to avoid skipping hidden files. I'm thinking about your other points :)

Comment: For `-paxmax-2x`, it could match on the `directory:` header. Some `ls` implementations output `./directory:`, some `directory:`. Which is why I used `ls -lALR ./` in my answer (even `ls -lALR .` would not be enough with some implementations).

Answer (score 3):

`ls` output can not generally be post-processed reliably.

If you can guarantee that file names don't contain newline characters, you could do:

```
ls -AlLR ./| grep -E '^-(..[[:lower:]]){3}'
```

That is print lines that start with `-` (regular files only) and for which the third character in every group of 3 characters in the pemission field is a lowercase letter (in practice, that will generally be either `x`, `s`, `l` or `t`. Some systems may have extensions, but would make it a lower case letter if the file is executable).

Note that it will only print the file name, not its full path.

With `zsh`, you can also do:

```
printf '%s\n' **/*(D-.f+111)
```

Or:

```
printf '%s\n' **/*(D-.f:a+x:)
```

From within `bash`:

```
zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" **/*(D-.f+111)'
```

I suppose you're using `-L` in your `find` approach because for symlinks, you want to check the target of the symlink. That's the purpose of the `-` flag above.

Note however that another side effect of `find`'s `-L` is that it would descend into symlinks to directories. The same will happen with `ls -LR`, not with that `zsh` solution above. If you really want to descend into symlinks to directories, replace the `**` with `***`, if you want to avoid descending into symlinks to directories with `find`, with GNU `find` (as found on Ubuntu), you can do:

```
find -L . \( ! -xtype l -o -prune \) -type f -perm -111
```

In any case, all those would fail to take into account files whose permissions alone would make them executable by every one but are sitting in directories that are not *searchable* by everyone. It could also give incorrect results if ACLs or other security measures are in place.

To also consider the *searchability* of the path components, you could do:

```
find -L . \( ! -xtype l -perm -111 -o -prune \) -perm -111
```

(assuming all the path components that lead to the current working directory itself are world-searchabe as well)

Comment: Funny "bash" answer!